# ¿Cómo deshacer el comando (alt gr) + (-) en atom?

Tags: atom-editor

me ha ocurrido un problema programando en c++. Resulta que he pulsado la tecla alt gr y - en atom (windows) y ha aparecido una columna a la derecha que no sirve para nada. He tratado de probar combinaciones de teclas, pero ninguna funciona. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar sería de gran interés.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema se puede solucionar con la combinacion de teclas `[ALT GR] + [=]`(para hacer `[=]` depende del teclado, en mi caso es con `[Shift] + [0]`)

**En resumen**:

`[ALT GR] + [-]`: Decrementa el ancho de la ventana que muestra el codigo.

`[ALT GR] + [=]`: Incrementa el ancho de la ventana que muestra el codigo.

**Fuente** [aqui](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-undo-alt-gr/39338/3).